# Python for loop multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a matrix of matrices that I need to do computations on (i.e. a x by y by z by z matrix, I need to perform a computation on each of the z by z matrices, so x*y total operations). Currently, I am looping over the first two dimensions of the matrix and performing the computation, but they are entirely independent. Is there a way I can compute these in parallel, without knowing in advance how many such matrices there will be (i.e. x and y unknown).

Comment: Yes, python can do this.

Comment: A full example including mathematical operations and realistic inputs (could be random numbers, but with a realistic shape) on what you have tried is always beneficial to get a good answer. ie. it is not known if you have a list of 2d-arrays or a simple 3d-array. Generally there are several ways (vectorized numpy solution, Numba, Cython,etc.) to efficiently implement such an algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; see the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Here's an example (tweaked from the one in the docs to suit your use case). (I assume `z = 1` here for simplicity, so that `f` takes a scalar.)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# x = 2, y = 3, z = 1 - needn't be known in advance
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

def f(x):
    # Your computation for each z-by-z submatrix goes here.
    return x**2

with Pool() as p:
    flat_results = p.map(f, [x for row in matrix for x in row])
    # If you don't need to preserve the x*y shape of the input matrix,
    # you can use `flat_results` and skip the rest.
    x = len(matrix)
    y = len(matrix[0])
    results = [flat_results[i*y:(i+1)*y] for i in range(x)]

# Now `results` contains `[[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36]]`
```

This will divide up the `x * y` computations across several processes (one per CPU core; this can be tweaked by providing an argument to `Pool()`).

Depending on what you're doing, consider trying vectorized operations (as opposed to for loops) with [numpy](https://numpy.org/) first; you might find that it's fast enough to make multiprocessing unnecessary. (If `matrix` were a numpy array in this example, the code would just be `results = matrix**2`.)

Answer (score 1):

The way I approach parallel processing in python is to define a function to do what I want, then apply it in parallel using `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap`. It's hard to suggest any code for your problem without knowing what you are computing and how.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def my_function(matrices_to_compare, matrix_of_matrices):
    m1 = matrices_to_compare[0]
    m2 = matrices_to_compare[1]
    result = m1 - m2 # or whatever you want to do
    return result

matrices_x = <list of x matrices>
matrices_y = <list of y matrices>

matrices_to_compare = list(zip(matrices_x,matrices_y))

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(my_function,
       [(x, matrix_of_matrices) for x in matrices_to_compare],
                                   chunksize=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the multiprocessing pool approach proposed by other answers - if you have a GPU available possibly the most straightforward approach would be to use a tensor algebra package taking advantage of it, such as `cupy` or `torch`.

You could also get some more speedup by jit-compiling your code (for cpu) with cython or numba (and then for gpu programming there's also `numba.cuda` which however requires some background to use).